# can i have shard collection without index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

i want shard a collection and this collection must have no any index (for fast insert operation). i create collection with autoIndexId : false and shard it, but when shard it, the mongo create index on shard key.
Now, Can I have a shard collection without any index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a shard collections allways needs an index that cannot be changed afterwards. This Index is needed to the distribution across multiple clusters.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/

Comment: So, How to increase speed of write operation. i use mongoimport to import data from file to database, max speed of write is 1500 per second, but i want increase it to 100K per second

Comment: you could change the journal settings: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-performance/